# Force service to end executing before assigning results to variable

Tags: angularjs

My real code is little complicated, so I wrote here simple one to just explain my question.

In every run, I want to get HTML template contents inside service, then assign them to variable in controller (or in `run`). After tracking the code I noticed that the service finished executing after `.run`.

```
angular.module("app",[])
run(function( $rootScope, service){
    var modules = {"a":{"name":"a"},"b":{"name":"b"}.....}
    $rootScope.innerHTML = service.gethtml(modules);
})
.controller("main", function($scope,service){
})
.service("service", function($http){
  this.gethtml = function(modules){
  var obj = {}; 
  angular.forEach(modules,function(module)){
    var template = "path/to/html";
    var innerHTML="";
    $http.get(template)
                .success(function(data){
                    module.innerHTML = data;
                })
                .error(function(data, status) {
                });
   //return innerHTML;  
   }
  return modules;
  }
})
```

In another words, I want to force `service` to finish executing before this assignment `$rootScope.innerHTML = service.gethtml;` in run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return promise.

```
angular.module("app",[])
run(function( $rootScope, service){

    service.gethtml().then(function(data){  
       $rootScope.innerHTML = data;
    });
})
.controller("main", function($scope,service){
})
.service("service", function($http, $q){
  this.gethtml = function(){
    var d = $q.defer();
    var template = "path/to/html";
    $http.get(template)
                .success(function(data){
                    d.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(error) {
                    d.reject(error);
                });
    return d.promise;  
  }
});
```

In my opinion it's not a good way to do this.

Comment: Can you suggest good ways? The hole idea is that I have JSON file of objects, and in every run I get those objects as well as adding new `innerHtML` property to them witch refer to each html template content in my project.
now the content may change to another language, so i need the new content, so i decide to get it in every run.
Do you have good ways, if I cleared my idea?

Comment: @HalaElBarchah What do you mean by 'every run'? What router are you using?

Comment: It's ngRouter.
Every run I mean every route

Comment: I can show you how it should look like using ui-router (you should use it instead of ngRouter).

Comment: I'm thinking about that, let me read about ui-router, then decide if i'll use it, because I have huge code to change so :(

Comment: I added some code to make it closer to what my code really looks like, maybe later I'll use ui-router. but now I need to solve that.. can you check what I added please! .. because I didn't know to solve it with your solution. @krutkowski86

Comment: @HalaElBarchah would you like to execute service.gethtml function on each state change or just on application run?

Comment: just on application run

Comment: I'll solve it in every route later, now I need to solve it in application run

Comment: @HalaElBarchah one more question... how does your response look like?

Comment: It should look like object of objects : `modules = {"a":{"name":"a","innerHTML":"text text text"},"b":{"name":"b","innerHTML":"text text text"}}`

Comment: The real data is more complicated, but I'm trying to simplify it to you as much as I can, and thank you alot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122194/discussion-between-krutkowski86-and-hala-el-barchah).